# Как описать функцию, возвращающую указатель на массив char?

Tags: c, c++

Или как заставить функцию вернуть std::string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>

std::string make_(void)
{
    std::string x ("hello");
    return x;
}

int main (void)
{
    std::cout << make_();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо. У меня почему то не компилируется. Видимо руки кривые.

Comment: Как именно не компилируется? Это C++ код.

Comment: Уже разобрался. Спасибо.

Comment: И в чем была проблема? В неправильном расширении файла? :-)

Answer (score 2):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
char* f(int size)
{
    char *s=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*size);
    return s;
}
int main()
{
    char *a=f(10);
    free(a);
    return 0;
}
```

Извините, теперь изменил под нормальный код =)

Comment: Тот кто вызвал функцию тот и будет ее чистить. Вы ведь пользуетесь функцией маллок, хотя она тоже возвращает указатель на динамически выделенную память и не чистит ее за собой.

Comment: Спасибо за "Си" :).